# What is it called when you lift yourself into a handstand?

Tags: gymnastics

What is the gymnastic term for, from standing on all fours, lifting yourself into a handstand in a controlled manner? That is, without kicking up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is called "[press to handstand](http://www.drillsandskills.com/article/16)".

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is called a handstand press.  It is where you are in a sort of straddle pose and you push your self up into a handstand without kicking.